# Passing pdf in a post request with other parameters in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, model

Hello what I am trying to do is create a registration page where user will enter his username , password and attach pdf file for his certificate. I want to send this model to my BE and store it in PostgreSQL. I have used file_picker so I can choose the PDF files and my model looks like this

```
class RegistrationModel{
  String username;
  String password;
  FilePickerResult certificate;
}
```

My question is how can I send this in post request, do I need to use MultipartRequest and if so how can I do it. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you trying to store a blob in SQL?

Comment: @AmateurCoder oh sorry I forgot to mention that part, we will store our pdf files in google drive